# For loop missing first row from mysql DB PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, html-table

I want to add data from phpmyadmin into a table format, but this code is missing the first row in the table and I don't understand why, I have tried other examples on SO such as

```
for ($i=0; $i< count($num); $i++)
```

But this did not work either.

Can someone see the issue?

Thanks

```
<?php

include('connect.php');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","******","*******","********");

$display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM markers");
$num = mysqli_num_rows ($display);
$col = mysqli_num_fields ($display);


$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($display);
$name = $row['name'];
?>



    <?php
        // start for loop

        for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($display); // fetching data
        //echo results to table
        echo "<tr data-name='$row[1]' data-address='$row[2]' data-lat='$row[3]' data-long='$row[4]'>";

        for ($j=0; $j <$col; $j++){ // looping through each row of table

        $test = $row [$j];
        echo "<td test='$test'>" . $row [$j] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn); // closing the connection
        ?>
```

Comment: How does `$num` get set? Also how does `$col` get set?

Comment: Code should go **into the question**, not into the comments.

Comment: You should also remove your db user, password and table

Comment: new to this, sorry

Comment: You already fetch the first row before the loop. It will therefor not be in the result set when you run through the loop. Though I would recommend using a while loop instead, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do it that way?
I'd do a fetch array and loop that.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM markers");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
     echo "<tr data-name='$row['dataName']' data-address='$row['Address']' data-lat='$row['LAT']' data-long='$row['LONG']'>"
  }
```

This would loop til you didn't have any more rows.

Comment: Sorry so you think that i don't need to assign variables to each fields and rows, how would that look though? Sorry I'm still pretty new to coding with php.

Comment: GOT ITT!! Thank you very much :D